# How to initialize a variable in a user defined MATLAB function(simulink)

Tags: matlab, function, user-defined-functions, simulink

I am trying to make a user defined function is simulink which looks something like this

```
 function [minTR,maxTR,out] = Temperature(u)
    [minTR] = min(u);
    [maxTR] = max(u);
    if((maxTR - minTR > 1.5))
        out = 1;
    else 
        out = 0;
    end
    end
```

Where `u` is a 1200x1 array for every sampling time , now the problem is I want is if this condition `if((maxTR - minTR > 1.5))` holds true I want the  `out` to remain 1 until the difference between maximum and minimum become less than lets say 0.7 , my plan was to set a `flag` which i would set in the condition to become 1 so my else code will look something like

```
    else if((maxTR - minTR < 1.5) && flag == 0)
        out = 0;
    end
```

but the problem is initialization , I have to initialize this flag once but simulink run this whole function for every sampling time and the flag would be reinitialized again and again , does anyone know what can i do to achieve that ?

Comment: What you are doing is a comparison and hystresis in series. Use readily made blocks.

Answer (score 0):

As *percusse* mentioned in the comments, you should look into already existing blocks (comparison + hysteresis) in the Simulink library.

In general, initialization of variables in Matlab/Simulink could be solved with [persistent](http://se.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ug/defining-and-initializing-persistent-variables.html) variables.

```
persistent flag

% If first run. Initialize flag.
if isempty(flag)
   flag = false;
end
```

An alternative is to take in an output signal from previous sample period by using the [delay block](http://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/unitdelay.html) which can be initialized with a value.